# preventDefault not working for keydown in Safari 5.0.4

Tags: jquery, safari, keydown, alt, preventdefault

I have the following code that binds Alt+b to do something:

```
(function(jQuery){
    $(document).ready(function() {
       $(document).bind('keydown', 'alt+b', function(event) {
        // do stuff
        event.preventDefault();
      });
    });
})( jQuery );
```

When using Safari browser (v5.0.4) on PC this triggers the menu to show (Bookmarks). Is there a way to prevent this behavior? preventDefault works with Chrome and Firefox in this case. I also tried to 'return false' but it doesn't work either.

***Note: it seems that my code works until I've made the menu visible for the first time. After that Alt+b triggers the bookmarks to show even if the menu is hidden.***

Comment: hi @jobzer, [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5483591/preventdefault-not-working-for-keydown-in-safari-5-0-4#answer-5483804) works in Safari on the PC.

Comment: @Alex, it seems that if I open Safari it works until I've opened the menu with Alt. After that Alt+b triggers the bookmarks to show even if the menu is hidden.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
(function(jQuery){
    $(document).ready(function() {
       $(document).bind('keydown', function(e) {
        if(e.keyCode==66){
          // do stuff
          e.preventDefault();
        }
      });
    });
})( jQuery );
```

Tested in safari, and it doesn't trigger bookmarks.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Have you tested with Safari v5.0.4 for Windows? It doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have your version of Safari (I couldn't test) but you can give this a try http://jsfiddle.net/LnvGR/2/

```
(function(jQuery){
   var keys = {};
$(document).keydown(function (e) {
    keys[e.which] = true;

    var kValues = '';
      for (var i in keys) {
          if (!keys.hasOwnProperty(i)) continue;
          kValues += i;
      }

     if (kValues == "1866" || kValues == "6618")
     {
         e.preventDefault();
         return false;
     }
});

$(document).keyup(function (e) {
    delete keys[e.which];
});

})( jQuery );
```

Reading all keys, then checking for the combination and calling preventDefault();

Comment: thanks, I tested it but unfortunately it didn't solve my problem.